# How to create Jenkins custom view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a way to add View to the Jenkins with standard configure options but completely redefined content of the view.
So far I only found adding the columns to the View but I want to change entire view.
Is it possible at all ?
If so any links from where I can start ?

Comment: Here's the entire source code of jenkins: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins

Comment: If you want to add colors and themes then u can find many themse online.